# Sort table in Django admin with a boolean field

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

I want to sort data by Boolean in Django admin, but it doesn't work with `admin_order_field`, below is my code :

```
 def get_is_active(self, obj):
        return obj.is_active
    get_is_active.allow_tags = True
    get_is_active.admin_order_field = 'is_active' 
    get_is_active.short_description = _('Is Active')
```

This is the image below :

[image]

Comment: What if you cllick on the triangle (next to `is active`) at the top?

Comment: Yes when I click on the triangle at the top it doesn't work

Comment: can you share the relevant model(s)?